How to prevent react native modal from moving up when keyboard opens in ios?
I tried to stabilise the modal, but when i touch the screen the modal goes upward and breaking down the style.
<Modal modalVisible={props.visibility} onClose={() => props.onclose()} avoidKeyboard={false}>
<KeyboardAvoidingView
behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : null`
style={{ flex: 1 }}
>
  <Loading loading={loading} />
  <Card containerStyle={styles.card}>
    <Text
      style={{
        color: colors.primaryColor,
        fontSize: 18,
        ...globalFonts.semiBold,
      }}>
      {t('ewallet_fund_transfer')}
    </Text>

    <InputItem
      required
      title={values[TRANSFER_TO]?.title}
      value={values[TRANSFER_TO].value}
      errorMessage={values[TRANSFER_TO].error}
      onchange={text => {
        handleChange(TRANSFER_TO, text);
      }}
      style={styles.inputItemStyle}
      inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
    />
    <InputItem
      currency
      keyboardType="decimal-pad"
      title={values[AMOUNT].title}
      value={values[AMOUNT].value}
      errorMessage={values[AMOUNT].error}
      onchange={text => {
        handleChange(AMOUNT, text);
      }}
      style={styles.inputItemStyle}
      inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
    />
    <InputItem
      currency
      editable={false}
      disabledStyle={styles.disableStyle}
      title={values[AVAILABLE_AMOUNT]?.title}
      value={values[AVAILABLE_AMOUNT].value}
      errorMessage={values[AVAILABLE_AMOUNT].error}
      onchange={text => {
        handleChange(AVAILABLE_AMOUNT, text);
      }}
      style={styles.inputItemStyle}
      inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
    />

    <InputItem
      required
      secureTextEntry
      title={values[TRANS_PASSWORD]?.title}
      value={values[TRANS_PASSWORD].value}
      errorMessage={values[TRANS_PASSWORD].error}
      onchange={text => {
        handleChange(TRANS_PASSWORD, text);
      }}
      style={styles.inputItemStyle}
      inputContainerStyle={styles.inputContainerStyle}
    />

    <Button
      title={t('submit')}`your text`
      buttonStyle={{
        backgroundColor: colors.primaryColor,
        marginTop: 10,
      }}
      onPress={() => submitHandler()}
    />
  </Card>


    
`this is my code and i cant able to understand where i made mistake`

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
